# CMS page with article list showing all articles from category without toolbar or pager

Tags: magento-1.7, products, toolbar, pager, cms-block

I'm almost there, but still have an issue with the display in the frontend.

I want to show some special products on the homepage which are linked to a certain category. These products will change regularly, i.e. monthly. Their order must be set by the option you have when calling the category in the administration and clicking the "products in this category" tab.

The reason for this is, that I don't wand to show them by the default order which is set in the frontend by the toolbar and pager of the "list.phtml".

What I have is this block call from a CMS page:

{{block type="catalog/product_list" display_type="all_products" column_count="15" category_id="52" template="catalog/product/list-start.phtml"}}

That template "list-start.phtml" is a derivate from the list.phtml - I have deleted the toolbar, the pager and the list view as well from it. So it basically is reduced to the grid view.

So far, so good.

The problem with this is, that I still have the default numer of articles shown in the frontend as anywhere else in the shop. Or, if I change 'my' numer of articles per page to, say, 20, that value is kept for my list-start.phtml, too, although there's no toolbar or pager anymore.

I recon, that this could be some JS issue or something saved in some cookie. What I'm looking for now, is something to override that default information and have all my 44 or 60 special articles nicely displayed in the grid and sorted by "position" which can be set in the list of articles in the category.

As it doesn't work with display_type="all_products" or column_count="15", I hope there's another option to get this done?

Any help ist greatly apprechiated!!

Answer (score 1):

I try to call a list of products from a CMS page.

Although I have tried in many ways, I didn't find a solution for this. Either you can call a list of products via some attribute but can't sort that list it in a way or you can sort the products of a givenn category but you can't escape the toolbar then.

But I found something else which I find quite noteworthy: when I call for a category by using

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="10" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Here, a product list is created with the toolbar. However, there's no pager! Although is says for example "product 1 to 12 of 35", there's no page navigation! This I found in 3 different Magento shops to be the case.

Can anybody approve this?
Is there a way to get the pager included, when calling category products from a CMS page?